# Does it affect performance to Cast ICollection to IDictionary in loops?

Tags: c#

```
for(var i=0; i< 10000; i++){
    ((IDictionary)resultCollection).Add(key, value);
}
```

In the code above, I am casting resultCollection(which is of type ICollection) to IDictionary. It is in for loop. Does it affect performance if it is done in loop(which will loop several thousand times)?

Comment: It most likely doesn't help. [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923882/how-expensive-is-casting-an-object).

Comment: Do you have a reason for *wanting* to keep it inside the loop? Do you think it affects the readability in some way?