# Which implementation of event handler give more performance?

Tags: c#, performance, event-handling

I used the same `TextChanged` event handler for 2 textboxs so Is their any performance improvement or it is just matter of readability?

**Method 1**

```
private void txtcode_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        //Some code
        }
private void txtname_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        //Some code
        }
```

**Method 2**

```
private void txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txtbx = (TextBox)sender;
        switch (txtbx.Name)
        {
            case "txtname":
                //Some code
                break;

            case "txtcode":
                //Some code
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: do you have a performance problem?

Comment: IMO, if you using 2 textbox, _you shouldn't have a performance issue_

Comment: Sounds like micro-optimization to me. Unless you have 1048576 different cases in your switch statement, I wouldn't even bother thinking about performance and go for readability.

Comment: The difference between those will be completely unmeasurable.

Comment: If (1) you don't have a performance problem and (2) you haven't measured, then always use the most readable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Method 1

will be better, as they are direct and knows for that control they are responding too

Regarding

#### Method 2

each time the sender(object) is casted to TextBox and then the switch statement decides the Operation on the control.

so it is obvious that, `Method1` will be more effective

---

Have a look at these links too : [How expensive is Casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923882/how-expensive-is-casting-an-object), [Performance of Typecasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165602/performance-of-typecasting)

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, the first method is faster. Practically, you wouldn't notice any difference. If your handlers share a good deal of code, using a `switch` is a perfectly acceptable way of reducing code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

There is no perfomance difference. There is also nothing wrong to have one handler for two text boxes if they have some common functionality or should be checked same way. The thing that you can improve is - do not check textboxes by the string name, better use their variable names like:

```
if(txtbx.Equals(txtcode))
     //...
```

If you refactor your code later, it will save you much time :)

Answer (score 1):

No difference in performance!!!!!!