# Serialize with JsonConvert

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

I have some classes in Windows Phone App:

```
[DataContract]
public class Function
{
    [DataMember(Name = "params")]
    public Params Parametrs { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Params
{
    [DataMember(Name = "params1")]
    public bool Params1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "params2")]
    public string Params2 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "params3")]
    public MyClass Params3 { get; set; }
 }


public string GetRequestString(Params parametrs)
{
    Function func = new Function()
            {    
                Parametrs = parametrs
            };
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(func);
    return json;
}

Params params = new Params()
  {
        Params1 = true,
        Params2 = "MyString",
        Params3 = myClassObject,
  }

  var json = GetRequestString(params);
```

My problem that `Params1`, `Params2`, etc. can have different types. I can't define it in one class Params.

Can I pass a set of parameters, types, keys to the function and serialize it in JSON?

Is this possible with JsonConvert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As c# is a strongly typed language, it requires that the type of a property be defined at compile time.  However, if you need objects to dynamic, you can use the `Object` base class. You may need to cast or convert them to relevant types before use however.

```
[DataContract]
public class Params
{
    [DataMember(Name = "params1")]
    public object Params1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "params2")]
    public object Params2 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "params3")]
    public object Params3 { get; set; }
}

Params param = new Params()
{
    Params1 = true,
    Params2 = "MyString",
    Params3 = new Object(),
};

var json = GetRequestString(param);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works fine. By the way, are very frequent cast will not affect the performance?

Comment: Not unless you are doing millions of casts without any other work - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165602/performance-of-typecasting.

Answer (score 0):

jsonconvert can serialize it here try property name to datamember Name=""
 eg:

```
[DataMember(Name = "Params1")]
 public bool Params1 { get; set; }
```